# Why the VideoPlayer provided by Unity3D is always lagging when I slide the notification bar?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video-player

I am developing an App for Android using Unity3D and Android Studio, which has been released on iOS platform, and its video player hadn't caused any trouble until I used it on Android: as I described in Title, the player would lag like plying a PowerPoint slowly in 3 following cases:

1. First time to install this App;
2. Slide the notification bar when playing;
3. Slide the Home Button(to show the running applications).

Curiously, after I click Home Button then wake up this App again, the player begins to normalise itself, it's smooth again.
Has anyone had this kind of problem and fixed them eventually? Or just tell me how can I find where the problem is, thanks a lot!

By the way, the test Phone is VivoX6, API = 22, Android 5.1